# Consuming a service API using nodejs + jsonwebtoken(jwt)

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt

Hello guys i want to use node.js to retrieve the user authenticated from an api URL.
I retrieved the codeToken(jsonwebtoken) and put it in the header of my request in postman it works.
But when i go to the code i can't find a way to use node.js+express request, to retrieve the json response of the user that's logged in using all that.
i can't put the url of the API in the sake of the client.
here is my code guys but it's not the right one please advise

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
url: '**********',//for the sake of client hidden
headers: {
tokenCode: '15288648455b20a04d5463e'
 }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
var info = JSON.parse(body);

console.log(info);

}else
//console.log(response  );
console.log(response.statusCode);
}

request(options, callback);
```

[Headers in my POSTMAN (only tokenCode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZcR.jpg)

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: actually my code sucks i don't know where to start with it so .. here it is don't judge please.

Comment: var request = require('request');
 
var options = {
  url: 'http://98.143.145.183/~api/api/neighbours',
  headers: {
    tokenCode: '15288648455b20a04d5463e'
  }
};
 
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);

    console.log(info);
    
  }else
    console.log(response );
   console.log(response.statusCode);
}
 
request(options, callback);

Comment: yeah ,I don't think anybody is gonna read code like this , you need to put it in the original question and format it. and also please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am sorry i couldn't find a way to put it in code format let me try again

Comment: I have edited my original post...

Comment: What do you mean by "cant find a way to retrieve the response"? What _does_ it return? Error status? Also please check if the header name (with case) is correct and if this is the only header, and request method etc are as expected (GET).

Comment: status is 405 and yes i only have that header to add the codeToken and that's the api i'm using actually i figured it's in my older comment you can try if you want to use it it's alraidy there for you all to see and the token also.
do you have any documentation or url i can follow?

Comment: 405 is [Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405). Your API most certainly isn't a GET. Probably a POST/PUT (which would make more sense because you don't want to expose token in URL generally).

Comment: owh yes it's a post request but how do i make it work in that case? what do i change thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Simple - instead of `request(...)` use `request.post(...)` (same arguments you pass to `request()`)

Comment: Re: in options{} i added method: 'post' 
now it's status 500 and it's even more bad for me :( can any one show me a step by step guide?

Comment: Your call is correct - 5xx error codes mean your API (server side) is having an issue. But if it works from POSTMAN, maybe you're sending something extra in POSTMAN which you haven't mentioned here - post a screenshot of POSTMAN here. Also, post the response body you get with 500 error.

Comment: ok, but in postman i only added tokenCode with that value that's all

Comment: check edit please @Vasan and thank you, you'r really helpfull

Comment: Ok, that's rather strange then, because with `method: 'post'` added, there should be no difference between the postman request and node request. I think at this point someone from the server-side/API team will have to tell you what went wrong on the server.